# Promoting semantically versioned artifacts when an upstream dependency has changed

Tags: gradle, nexus, git-flow, semantic-versioning

I am in the midst of an initiative to convert our build.gradle files to use semantic versions. In addition to using Gradle, we also use Git and are following the Gitflow Workflow. Jenkins is used to build the projects.

Versions for released artifacts follow a MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format. When declaring dependencies in the build.gradle file, we use dynamic versions, such as 10.0.+ (i.e. take the latest 10.0.PATCH version).

We promote our artifacts from a Release Candidates repository to a Releases repository in Nexus. The repository has its policy set to "Releases". Because of the complexity of the product (200+ projects, with many upstream and downstream dependencies), a lot of the promotion plugins available for Jenkins appear to fall short. We were thinking of having Jenkins build the master branch as a way to rename artifacts (10.0.0-rc.1-abcdefg becomes 10.0.0) and upload them to the correct Nexus repository.

I am unsure of how to handle a situation where an upstream dependency has a patch version incremented. The downstream project - a WAR - is re-built by Jenkins and bundles the new JAR, but the version of the downstream project doesn't change. When an attempt is made to upload to Nexus, it fails because only one artifact can have the same version.

Here is an example:

- The Releases Nexus repository has upstream-api versioned at 10.0.0, and downstream-project versioned at 10.0.0
- downstream-project depends on 10.0.+ of upstream-api
- upstream-api.jar is bundled into the downstream-project.war file
- The two artifacts are deployed as part of Release X of the product
- When a hotfix branch has been merged into master, the upstream-api version has changed to 10.0.1
- The fix means that when deployed, the product is now Release X'
- downstream-project stays at 10.0.0, but is re-built because of the change in the upstream dependency
- Jenkins fails to upload downstream-project-10.0.0.war to Nexus because it already exists

I could have the old artifact replaced with the new artifact, but then that means that Release X can no longer be deployed from artifacts in Nexus (eg. in the case of a rollback, or needing to replicate an issue on an older release).

How is this typically handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is this typically handled?

I don’t have a universal answer here. I would assume that these are the most “common” possibilities:

- Don’t distribute your dependencies with the release and continue to use dependency version declarations such as `10.0.+`. The assumption is then that the software will indeed work with *any* 10.0.x version – at least as far as your users will tolerate it. That usually happens for free software which is distributed in source or in a package system of a Linux distribution. The dependency version declaration is only updated when there is a required improvement in the dependency, i.e., when the change is so important that your users won’t tolerate any earlier version.
- Distribute your dependencies with the release and either:

  - Use a build number in addition to the main/semantic version number of the original code – for example 1.3.4-b3. If I’m not mistaken, then this is often being done for proprietary Windows software.
  - Increment the main/semantic version number when a dependency changes and make the dependency requirement explicit.

### Some more General Thoughts on the Issue

I think the core issue is the dynamic dependency declaration – the `10.0.+` version declaration. What you state with this declaration is that your release will work *equally well* with *any* 10.0.x version.

- If that is really the case, i.e., the bugs that are fixed by a patch in the dependency are *guaranteed* to *never* affect the release, then your release should probably simply not be rebuilt, since its functionality wouldn’t change anyway. The version of the dependency wouldn’t matter, your release could stay with the older dependency version.
- More likely, though, the upstream bugfixes will also make a difference in your downstream project, i.e., they will affect the functionality of the release. In that case you should make the “new” dependency explicit in your `build.gradle`. Since that’s a change to your release artifact, a new release version is due.

Comment: I thought about explicitly stating dependencies in the build.gradle file, but when I reviewed the http://semver.org site, that seems to fall under Tom Preston-Werner's definition of version lock - the inability to upgrade a package without having to release new versions of every dependent package. I also thought about doing the opposite of your first bullet; i.e. if a fix is really a hotfix, then Release X should never be deployed without it (Release X'), so keeping artifacts to reconstitute Release X is no longer necessary.

Comment: Please read Tom’s definition of “version lock” again carefully: he speaks about locking the version of the _upstream_ package, i.e., of your library – not of the downstream/dependent package! In other words, if semantic versioning would _not_ be used upstream, then the upstream package maintainer would have to constantly fear that _“dependent”_ (downstream) packages would have to be released, too, whenever the upstream package is released in a new version.

Comment: Actually it seems to me that you are fearing “dependency hell” _despite_ using semantic versioning: you are trying to release the downstream package whenever the upstream package changes. I guess you should trust your semantic versions (and not re-release downstream) ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, Chriki. I realized after re-reading my post that I had called downstream-project a JAR, when it is a WAR (I have since edited it). Due to some peculiarities with the way APIs and dependencies are defined for our project, I think there will have to be instances where a simple update requires some version changes in the downstream WAR so that it bundles the new JAR. We won't be able to leverage all the advantages of semantic versioning at first, but can work over time to get there. Most of our project will conform and it will just be some special cases.

Comment: I admittedly don’t know the “peculiarities” of your project, however, it sounds that you are just one step away from semantic versioning: when your downstream WAR needs to change for some simple update in the upstream library, then you should simply increase the major version number of the upstream library (as per (8) in the SemVer spec). In order to use the new version downstream, you will then have to change the dependency version downstream, too, and make the required code changes. That will both also require a new version for your WAR but then deploying to Nexus won’t be a problem anymore.